# Why do I get "incorrect password" response even though it is correct?

Tags: javascript, authentication, postman

I am posting some input via postman to login a user. The problem is, whenever I input the correct password, Postman states that I have inputted the wrong password, even though it is definitely correct. This is the user I am trying to login:
[image: This]

Edit: When I say Postman says I inputted the wrong password, I mean its giving me the `"Password is wrong"` answer from this line: `if(!validPass) return res.status(400).send("Password is wrong");`

Edit 2: This is what I am inputting in Postman by the way:
[image: This]

Here is the login process:

```js
//LOGIN:
router.post('/login',async(req,res)=>{  

    //Validation
    const{error} = loginValidation(req.body);
    if(error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);

    //If user already in db
    const u = await User.findOne({email:req.body.email});
    if(!u) return res.status(400).send("Email is wrong");

    //Password check
    const validPass = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password,u.password);
    if(!validPass) return res.status(400).send("Password is wrong");
    res.send("A ok");
});
```

For a broader context, here is my full project: https://plnkr.co/edit/ydQwisGd3kVC06RqvhjR?p=catalogue
A "/" in the name means "folder/file". Otherwise its in the root.

Thanks.

Comment: What's `bcrypt.compare` ? What does it return in your case?

Comment: ```bcrypt.compare()``` compares the password the user just inputted to the password in the database associated with that email. So if ```req.body.password``` and ```u.password``` is correct, the user can login.

Comment: Are you sure you're not comparing 2 hashes? i.e that u.password is hashed, and that req.body.password is also hashed, so the bcrypt returns false

Comment: I also think what @octohedron said, the first parameter of compare should be a plaintext password and the second the hash found in the database, it seems req.body.password is already hashed

Comment: In this example, the password is hashed. But the same result appears for non hashed password too. Here is the proof: https://i.imgur.com/LDTryiQ.png And here is what I put in postman: https://i.imgur.com/kTcYdu3.png

Comment: Could you, right after the **//Password check** comment, log both re.body.password and u.password to see at that point what's going into the check?

Comment: Okay, here were my results: https://i.imgur.com/jTCVmrM.png     The password printed ```12334567_2```, the correct password for the user I inputted. But now I am still confused. ```req.body.password``` and ```u.password``` are exactly the same, so why isn't the login going through??

Comment: "...`req.body.password` and `u.password` are exactly the same...".  This is why it's failing.  The first value needs to be the plaintext (the password submitted in the input form) but the second needs to be the hash to compare against

Comment: Which `bcrypt` library are you using? (That's what I meant with "What's bcrypt.compare?")

Answer (score 0):

I wanted the `u.password` equal `req.body.password` when the correct password was entered to the correct email, else don't log them in. Here is what I came up with:

```js
const user_password = u.password;
    const password_history = req.body.password;
    if(user_password != password_history) return res.status(400).send("Password is wrong");
```